#  Import Email from AD Mailbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, exchange-server

We have an old legacy SQL 2000 server (the last in the farm) – We’ve been unable to get rid of this server as it uses `xp_findnextmsg`, `xp_readmail` etc to monitor a mailbox (via mapi) and import all email to that address into a database. The database contains simple tables that store "from", "to", "subject", "body", "Sent Date" & so on.

As you may know, the procs above are no longer in use in SQL 2005+

This table is read from dozens of internal systems, for instance emails to this mailbox can be automatically picked up by our helpdesk systems & create calls etc.

My question is this: what it the easiest / modern way of doing this in SQL 2008+? Is it going to be a case of writing a .net binary / service that will use smtp or something to connect to a mailbox and insert the data into SQL or is there a simpler way to do it? (SSIS / 3rd party tools / pre-existing code / projects?)

Just thought I’d ask before i start writing something – no point re-inventing the wheel as it were.

PS: The Mailbox in question is an exchange 2010 mailbox.

**Edit:** This functionality was hinted to be re-introduced in 2008 & dbmail: http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/126167/xp-readmail-replacement-for-sql-2005 but it looks like it failed to materialise!

**Edit 2**: I've just found a decent code sample here that utilises the new web services in exchange 2007+: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/dd2b465b-b1d2-4c0d-82ec-c36c6c482d5d - experimenting in progress (has anyone ever worked with SQL and the Exchange web services?)

**Edit 3**: All done! I knocked up a .net service that sits on our exchange server and monitors a mailbox & pushes any new mail into SQL. Incase others have a similar question and need some sample code to get started - here is some rough code (chopped out of my service - replaced parameterised SQL with basic dynamic SQL for easy reading): (Note: you’ll need the EWS API 1.1 dll)

```
Imports Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data

Dim ExchangeUrl As String = "https://DOMAIN.co.uk/ews/exchange.asmx"
Dim service As New ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1)
service.Url = New Uri(ExchangeUrl)
service.Credentials = New WebCredentials("USER@DOMAIN.CO.UK", "PASSWORD")
Dim findResults As FindItemsResults(Of Item) = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, New ItemView(1000))
If findResults.Count > 0 Then
    service.LoadPropertiesForItems(findResults.Items, New PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties))
End If

For Each item As Item In findResults.Items
    Dim CurrentEmail As EmailMessage = item

    '#### Grab Email Information
    E_ID = CurrentEmail.InternetMessageId.ToString()
    If CurrentEmail.Sender.Address.ToString() <> "" Then
        E_From = Replace(CurrentEmail.Sender.Address, "'", "''")
    Else
        E_From = Replace(CurrentEmail.Sender.Name, "'", "''")
    End If
    E_From = Replace(CurrentEmail.Sender.Address, "'", "''")
    E_To = Replace(CurrentEmail.DisplayTo, "'", "''")
    E_CC = Replace(CurrentEmail.DisplayCc, "'", "''")
    E_Subject = Replace(CurrentEmail.Subject, "'", "''")
    E_Body = Replace(CurrentEmail.Body.Text, "'", "''")
    E_Received = CurrentEmail.DateTimeReceived.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
    E_Sent = CurrentEmail.DateTimeSent.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

    '#### Save the email into SQL
    If SqlQuery("INSERT INTO tbl_Emails ([MessageID], [From], [To], [CC], [Subject], [Body], [Received], [Sent]) VALUES ('" & E_ID & "', '" & E_From & "', '" & E_To & "', '" & E_CC & "', '" & E_Subject & "', '" & E_Body & "', CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & E_Received & "', 103), CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & E_Sent & "', 103))") = True Then
        item.Delete(DeleteMode.HardDelete)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Glad everything worked out for you.  You should move edit 3 to an answer so people can vote it up :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind for me is SQL CLR.  MAPI is [not specifically supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2009/04/03/mapi-and-net.aspx) in .net (at least to my knowledge), although there are [work arounds](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2048/Simple-MAPI-NET).
Reading from an exchange mailbox, luckily, is supported in [host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813349) of [situations](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480).

BTW,I've found working with email in .net to be relatively pain free.

Comment: EWS definitely seems to be the way to go – setting your response as answer.